# When I lock my computer, some sort of macro is run. How do I find the offending program?

Tags: windows, malware, lock-screen

**Problem:**
Frequently (~5%) of the time, when I lock the computer (win + L), the computer goes to the lock screen then the "Project" window (w + P) is displayed almost immediately, followed by:

When I log back in, there are a number of windows open, including:

- 5-6+ instances of windows explorer(.exe) (win + e)
- 2 instaces of 'Run' (win + R)
- Settings (win + I)
- Visual Studio (win, v, i, s)

**Env:**
My computer (desktop) runs lots of software, such as editing, developer, game, and general programs; python websockets, autohotkey, a number of anti-cheats (from games), etc. . The list of programs run is extensive enough that I can't easily identify which program(s) are the offenders.

**What I have tried:**
I've used the event viewer to find any strange events, but there seem to be none.

**What I need help with:**
I'm looking for a way to troubleshoot this behaviour. I'm at a bit of a loss of what terms to use to search for a solution.

aka: my google-fu sucks. I'd appreciate any help on how I should approach this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a long damn time to figure out. It appears that this is caused by autohotkey (on Windows).

The culprit code:

```
sc05C up::
    Send, Overuse of formatting, such as ALL CAPS,
Return
```

sc05C is the hotkey for `International 6` using the iCUE software (for Corsair 'gaming' keyboards), which I have mapped to my G13 key. iCUE does not have to be running for this issue to occur.

By locking my computer using `Win + L`, the sc05C hotkey is somehow triggered, resulting in the macro executing mid lock - This means the `Send` string is called, but with the `Win` key **pressed before** the `Send`.

This is effectively running:

```
Send, {Win Down}Overuse of formatting, such as ALL CAPS,{Win Up}
```

with the computer lock happening at some point, usually before the letter "P" in "CAPS".

---

Edit 1: It could have something to do with sc05C == vkEA, which the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) say:

`0xE9-F5 | OEM specific`

---

Edit 2: Tested it using vkEA and it does not cause the issue. I believe sc05C was originally used since vkEA was not properly called using an older version of CUE v2. Using iCUE v3.27.68, it does work.